# Uninstalling Software using SCCM 2012

Tags: sccm

We have several version of a software that we need to uninstall through our computers in our company (743 in total) I am new to SCCM and was wondering if someone could help me with this task.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the basic function of Configuration Manager (application/package management). It's not what problem you encountered but asking for something, it's better that you post to Microsoft [Technet Forum for Configuration Manager.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=configmanagerapps)

In my opinion, one of the easy way is to write a batch script. In this script, you need to specify lines of uninstalling commands which works to uninstall each software. It's an option that you put each software on a network share so that if the uninstall command need to call the installer, you can use UNC path.

After you creating the batch file then you need Configuration Manager to deploy it to clients. Example steps as below:  (assume all your clients has been already managed by Configuration Manager. If not, see SCCM [Discovery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712308.aspx#BKMK_ADSystemDisc) and Agent Installation)

**Steps:**

1. Create a collection of these clients. It's also fine that you create several collections based on different client OS (Win 7, win 8.1, win 10).
2. Create a package with source file (the batch script) and create a program to execute the batch. If the batch needs specific admin permission to uninstall softwares, you need to use 'Run as administrator' option.
3. Deploy the package to above collections (assume your distribution points and other necessary configurations are out there)
4. Monitor the status of the deployment.

Above is one methods to do this, there are lots of ways and you need to learn